# RxSwift Textfield debounce subscribe is not calling

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Changes after 0.3 seconds when user stop typing should be displayed in label but subscribe onNext is not calling

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    textfield.rx.text.orEmpty
        .debounce(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] (text) in
            self.label.text = text
        }).disposed(by: disposebag)
    ...
}
```

Using **Swift 5**

```
pod 'RxSwift', '~> 5'
pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 5'
```

Comment: Works just fine for me...

Comment: it is not working for me check this video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m4QpXoaK4xBtXktH0kO8mh0V3ovmrn36/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to declare `disposebag` outside of the `viewDidLoad()` scope:

```
let disposebag = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...

    textfield.rx.text.orEmpty
        .debounce(.milliseconds(1000), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] (text) in
            self.label.text = text
            print("Yo")
        }).disposed(by: disposebag)
}
```

Since in your code, the `disposebag` lives inside the `viewDidLoad()` scope, once this method ends, the `disposebag` is deallocated, which cancels the subscription.

Comment: but why declare disposebag outside of the viewDidLoad() scope

Comment: because the viewDidLoad() scope will end, the bag will go nil, and thus release your stream. If the bag is at parent object scope level it will be released with the object.